# Associating text strings with functions

Tags: c++, string

Here's my solution, which requires a test run to compute the const values before it is functional. That's awkward, do you have a more graceful solution? I was thinking I'd avoid calling 100 string comparisons doing it this way.

```
//find these values before hand
char a[] = "SHET"; //1413826643
char b[] = "ANIM"; //1296649793
char c[] = "RGST"; //1414743890
int* get_word_value[] = { (int*)a, (int*)b, (int*)c };

//enum in header file makes it externally linked and compatible with switch statement
enum str_command{ SHET = 1413826643, ANIM = 1296649793, RGST = 1414743890 } ;
//cpp:
char* file = readTXT( "text.txt" );
int* command = (int*)file;
switch( command ) {
case SHET: SHETfunc( file ); break;
case ANIM: ANIMfunc( file ); break;
case RGST: RGSTfunc( file ); break;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Use a std::unordered_map ?

Comment: enum str_command{ SHET = 'TEHS', ANIM = 'MINA', RGST = 'TSGR' } ; (reversed for little endian)

Comment: I don't understand why you have to run the program to compute your constant values. This can be done fairly easily by hand and the "magic number" plugged into the source.

Comment: The point of the code is to process the file based on commands. This would be done in a loop until the end of file. Thanks to cppguy, that is the functionality I wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not

```
 std::map<std::string, std::function<here goes what the return types etc are>> dispatch;

Then

 dispatch["a string"](args);
```

You can initialise the list with `map_list_of` from boost

Answer (score 1):

Another popular method is to use a look up table:

```
typedef void (*Function_Pointer)(/* input parameters*/);

struct Name_Function_Entry
{
  std::string  name;
  Function_Pointer function;
};

void Shet(void);
void Anim(void);
void Rgst(void);

const Name_Function_Entry function_table[] =
{
  {"SHET", Shet},
  {"ANIM", Anim},
  {"RGST", Rgst},
};
const unsigned int number_of_entries =
  sizeof(function_table) / sizeof(function_table[0]);

// ...
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < number_of_entries; ++i)
{
   if (name == function_table[i].name)
   {
      (function_table[i].function)();
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why on earth would he do a linear search when he could use a map or unordered_map?

Comment: For small data sets, the time difference between linear an other searches is negligible.  The linear search is easy to understand, and doesn't require sorted data.  If the data were sorted, the OP could use a binary search, thus having performance about equal to a map.